# serverless.yml to invoke python

Tags: python, aws-lambda, serverless

I am trying to deploy python lambda function with serverless framework. This function need to run for 15 min (AWS Lambda Timeout). I want to simulate 100 IoT devices using AWS Lambda.

I have following code `device_status.py`

```
import os
import time
from uptime import uptime
import requests
from random import randrange
from configparser import ConfigParser, ExtendedInterpolation



class DeviceStatus:

    def __init__(self):

        self.config_file = 'config.ini'
        self.config_dict = None
        self.read_device_config()
        self.dr_ins = DeviceRegistration(self.config_dict)

....

if __name__ == '__main__':

    init_ds = DeviceStatus()
    status_interval = init_ds.config_dict['status']['interval']
    while True:
        init_ds.send_device_status()
        time.sleep(int(status_interval))
```

and `serverless.yml`

```
service: lambda-device

plugins:
   - serverless-python-requirements

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  region: us-east-1

functions:
  lambda-device:
    handler: main.device_status
```

when I try to invoke it I get `"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'main'"`

How to refer to main function in `serverless.yml` ?

Comment: Are you trying to create AWS Lambda? If so you'll need a handler (e.g def handler_name(event, context): ). https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html

Comment: Also I see you're using serverless-python-requirements. Personally never used it because I go with lambda layers but given the code you provided I wanted to suggest to you when importing for speed-up of your lambda cold-start you should follow pep-20 `Explicit is better than implicit.` on imports Ex: `from os import environ`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message that you are receiving is saying that there is no `main.py` file in your serverless structure.
Referring to your `serverless.yml`:

```
functions:
  lambda-device:
    handler: main.device_status
```

The explanation from the above section is that you have a serverless-function that is named `lambda-device` which is having a structure with a filename `main.py` that in its definition would require to have a method:

```
def device_status(event, context):
    # TODO
    pass
```

So make sure you have `main.py` file with a method `device_status(event, context)`